# Multiple fork()'s. How does main know pid?

Tags: c, process, fork, pipe

I am writing a C program that creates # childs and let's them do a single task and report the result back to the main. After writing to the pipe they have to wait for another request.

I have communication in one direction working with a pipe but I have no way of knowing where (or better, from who) the data is coming from.

Is there any way to know the child's PID in the parent when there is no way of knowing which child wrote on the pipe?

**Edit**
I have an array with all PID's of the childs but when reading out the pipe, I have no way of knowing where the data came from.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you not know where it's coming from?

Comment: Because I don't have a way of knowing which child wrote to the pipe.

Answer (score 4):

Create one pipe for each child and use `select` or `poll` to listen to all of them at once.

Answer (score 3):

Either do like Zack says (one pipe per child) or change your protocol in such a way that the child reports its pid as part of the message.

Answer (score 0):

fork() returns the pid of the child to the parent process and 0 to the child, you could store them in an array or link list to keep track of them